# How to allow anyone to submit issue for a private repo?

Tags: github

I have a private repo. I have users using the app. I'd like for them to be able to report bugs using GitHub. I've read the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-an-issues-only-repository) and I just don't get if it would be possible to automatically close issues on Public repo once the corresponding issue is closed in Private repo.

I guess that the workflow should be something like:

- user creates issue in Public repo
- I recreate the issue in Private repo and I add a comment to Public repo that issue has also been created in Private repo
- once the issue is resolved in Private repo I need to manually close the corresponding ticket in Public repo (I would add as much details as I'm allowed)

Is this the only way to do it? Is there some way to automatically create new issue in Private repo once there is issue in Public repo?

Comment: You're referring to the correct dosc page. Maybe a case for https://support.github.com?

Answer (score 0):

3 Step Process :

1. Go to your private repo and click on `settings`
2. Then Click on Invite `Collaborator`
3. Click `Add people`
4. Input username or email who want to be invited
5. Click `Select a collaborator above`

Comment: This would work if I know who will submit issue so I can add them, but what if I want for anyone to be able to open an issue?